# Azure DevOps Pipeline - How to reference a value from a loop in a stage condition

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm receiving the following error in Azure DevOps when trying to run my pipeline. I am trying to reference a value from an each loop inside a stage condition. What am I doing wrong?

Code -

```
- ${{ each env in split(variables.environments, ',') }}:
    - stage: deploy${{ env }}Stage
      displayName: "Deploy ${{ env }}
      dependsOn:
        - dockerStage
      condition: ${{ eq(parameters.deployTo${{ env }}, true) }}
```

Error -

```
Unexpected symbol: 'deployTo${{'. Located at position 15 within expression: eq(parameters.deployTo${{ env
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#format) to append `${{ env }}` to part of the parameter name, so that the pipeline is able to construct a complete parameter name for evaluation.

In addition, there are two options for you to modify the pipeline.

**Use stage condition property**

```
condition: ${{ eq(parameters[format('deployTo{0}', env)], true) }}
```

```
parameters:
- name: deployToTEST
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: deployToQA
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: deployToPROD
  type: boolean
  default: true

variables:
- name: environments
  value: Test,QA,PROD

stages:
- stage: dockerStage
  jobs:
  - job: dockerJob
    steps:
    - script: |
        docker --version

- ${{ each env in split(variables.environments, ',') }}:
  # - ${{ if eq(parameters[format('deployTo{0}', env)], true) }}:
    - stage: deploy${{ env }}Stage
      displayName: "Deploy ${{ env }}"
      dependsOn:
        - dockerStage
      condition: ${{ eq(parameters[format('deployTo{0}', env)], true) }}
      jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
        - script: |
            echo environment is ${{ env }}
```

[image]

**Use conditional insertion**

```
- ${{ if eq(parameters[format('deployTo{0}', env)], true) }}:
```

```
parameters:
- name: deployToTEST
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: deployToQA
  type: boolean
  default: true
- name: deployToPROD
  type: boolean
  default: true

variables:
- name: environments
  value: Test,QA,PROD

stages:
- stage: dockerStage
  jobs:
  - job: dockerJob
    steps:
    - script: |
        docker --version

- ${{ each env in split(variables.environments, ',') }}:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters[format('deployTo{0}', env)], true) }}:
    - stage: deploy${{ env }}Stage
      displayName: "Deploy ${{ env }}"
      dependsOn:
        - dockerStage
      # condition: ${{ eq(parameters[format('deployTo{0}', env)], true) }}
      jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
        - script: |
            echo environment is ${{ env }}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Also, thank you for the alternative logic of moving the condition to an if statement outside the stage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **if else expression** to make it simple.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: environments
    value: prod1,prod2 

steps:  
- ${{ each env in split(variables.environments, ',')}}:
  - ${{ if eq(env, 'prod1') }}:
    - script: echo "environemtn is  ${{ env }}"
      displayName: test1
```

> condition keyword need pass in the parameters or static variables, dynamically generated variables seems can not be used.